# Where are the air vents located on ships in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-discovery, star-trek-picard

In *Star Trek: Discovery, "Perpetual Infinity,* Michael Burnham and the Discovery crew manage to trap Michael's mother in a containment field. It was set up like a dome around her. Here's a pic:

[image: Star Trek Discovery Containment Field]

The containment field is barely visible. Here's a better one:

[image: Star Trek Discovery Containment Field Failure]

Michael Burnham's mother was *not* in a room. So how did she get oxygen? It would be impossible for oxygen to pass through the containment field, and that would mean that it had to come up through the floor. Would that mean that there were air vents in the floor? I remember in an episode in Star Trek Voyager, the EMH Doctor, or just "Doctor" contained someone in med bay in a containment field of the exact same shape. He ordered the computer to put a different gas *inside* the containment field. The containment field was not connected to the wall or ceiling. Yet the gas entered the containment field without it being lowered. 1980s-90s *Star Trek* shows have carpet on their ships, and there would have been no space for air vents in the floor. So where are the air vents, and how do they get oxygen or other gases into containment fields?

Anyways, back to the question. Where are air vents located, and how do they get it to contained objects/organisms?

Comment: Why do you assume that a force field that's transparent and can be talked through is gas-impermeable?

Comment: @Valorum Because if it were, containment fields would be useless when there are hull breaches. Like in Star Trek: Nemesis, when a torpedo blew a hole in the viewscreen, and a containment engaged, keeping the vacuum from sucking everyone out. So why exactly did you downvote my post?

Comment: Why would you assume the EMH's command to the computer wouldn't have caused a generation / transport of gas into the given section.

Comment: Unless you haven't seen anything like that happening, which is impossible because they've shown it _onscreen_ so many times.

Comment: @NKCampbell My question is **_HOW_** that gas was transported into the containment zone.

Comment: also - in addition to the answer I made, iirc there was an episode where Data either released a sedative or a waking gaseous agent against the bridge crew, but I can't find it at the moment

Comment: @NKCampbell - TNG: Brothers

Comment: Force fields can have holes, as seen in discovery, season 1, episode 2!

Comment: @Philipp Flenker That is very possible, but when Michael Burnham was in the brig in the episode "Battle at the Binary Stars," there was a hull breach _in_ the brig, and the only thing keeping her from the cold vacuum of space was the containment field. If there were holes in it, Michael Burnham would be long forgotten in Star Trek Discovery, or rather remembered as the one who started the Klingon-Federation War.

Comment: @ Philipp Flenker Plus, when Captain Leland used a phaser rifle to shoot the containment field, if there were holes, Michael Burnham's mother would have been shot. Am I losing you here, or did you actually watch the episode?

Comment: The escape sequence from the brig clearly shows that the Computer can easily open and close holes in the containment field. I don't see why this would be any different a few episodes later.

Comment: A 2m high hemisphere holds 16700 liters of air. At 8 liters per minute, that would last 35 hours. Why is more oxygen needed?

Comment: The only reason I'm here is because of my interest in Star Trek. I hope this is a safe online place where I can ask good questions and get answers to my curiosities. Is this really a safe place? Because I saw in SE: Meta that someone was getting death threats just for posting a question that made others slightly upset.

Comment: This is about as safe as it gets for online places, I think. Of course there are some crazy people anywhere, but Stack Exchange is pretty strictly moderated and any blatantly offensive behaviour (like death threats etc) is usually shut down quickly and the offenders banned. Don't worry about that.

Comment: @MarkusRutledge The scene in your picture doesn't even take place on a ship.

Comment: It doesn't have to be on a ship.

Comment: @Markus Rutledge  Isn't the main breathing problem that affects someone first not the depletion of oxygen, but the build up of suffocating carbon dioxide?  If the air can't circulate, the build up of carbon dioxide will probably kill before the lack of oxygen..

Comment: Why is this question so downvoted?

Comment: @1252748 *I don't know!* I just asked a question, and all of a sudden they're angry because I didn't consider the fact that there are different types of force fields!

Comment: That's why I tried to delete the post, because people would just try to seize the opportunity to downvote my question. But of course, it won't let me, and I can't disassociate it because it *is* my question.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry don't do it, I upvoted it, moreover there is a very good answer that would be lost

Comment: In a TOS episode (I don't remember which) a shuttle comes in the hangar and some members of the crew are there. Evidently the field has particular properties, such as adaptability by reaction to some elements like e.g. the material of a shuttle, to open a hole corresponding to the contour/section of the body structure

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question mainly revolves around how it is possible to get breathable atmosphere into sections contained by a force field. You assume that air vents are needed for that, therefore you ask where they are located, but I think that this assumption is not correct.

## There are different types of force fields

Thoughout the canon, we see that there are loads and loads of different types of Force Fields. The accepted answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146956/why-and-when-would-you-use-a-lower-level-forcefield) provides us with an overview over the varying degrees of force fields that we see in the canon. In at least one case, it was explicitly mentioned that the force field was erected to keep oxygen out:

> **SEVEN**: Let's play another game. Let's imagine that the oxygen on the bridge has been depleted.
>   **TRAJIS**: What?
>   **SEVEN**: What do you suppose the results might be? Computer, seal the bridge with a level three forcefield.

*(Voy: One)*

There are also different scales for different types of field (Dampening Fields, Biohazard Fields, Containment Fields and so on).

I recommend reading the answer to the other question, it's really good! The main implication I want to point out is that if you need a certain level of force field to hold an atmosphere (Level 7 for the atmosphere in Voy: Demon, for example), it's implied that lower level force fields won't be able to properly do the job, potentially leaking the atmosphere.

## There are different shapes of force fields

Force fields are what makes holograms "touchable". If I recall correctly, holodecks use a combination of replicators and force fields, which makes it entirely possible that every fabric the characters touch or breathe through is not a force field, but an actual replicated piece of cloth - however, it's obvious that force fields are much more than just two dimensional "windows" with energy.

It's established in Discovery, Season 1, Episode 2, that at the era of Discovery, the computer is able to change the shape of a force field:

[image: Burnham escaping from the brig]

In this image, you see the computer opening a big hole into the force field.

The implication is that it's not far fetched to assume that it's possible to erect force fields with enough holes in it to let air pass through it.

## This specific field served a specific purpose - which wasn't to isolate Burnham's mother

Now that we have established that force fields come in many varieties and shapes, let's take a closer look at the force field in question.

The main point of this force field was to keep Gabrielle Burnham from being pulled back into the future. While the episode offers a lot of technobabble as an explanation, nothing in this episode indicates that in order to do that, Gabrielle needed to be isolated completely and 100% from her surroundings. You can even see in the picture you have posted that this containment field has some kind of honeycombed structure - it reminds me of a Faraday cage, which protects you from thunderbolts even though it has big enough holes in it for you to safely breathe.

Comment: great answer, very specific

Comment: Thanks so much! That was the answer I was looking for. It was an amazing answer.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qdv5.png - VOY: Repentance

Answer (score 4):

In the TNG episode - "[The Hunted](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hunted_(episode))" air-vents are shown releasing a [sedative](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Anesthizine) gas:

[image]

Comment: I can't see the picture because I'm on a school chromebook, but I'm assuming they're coming from vents near the ceiling?

Comment: The containment field sealed Michael's mom off from the rest of the room, so there was _no_ way the oxygen could have reached her.

Comment: I don't exactly have the answer I want, but something is better than nothing.

Comment: @MarkusRutledge - Your strong assertion that these forcefields are gas-impermeable needs some sort of reference to back it up.

Comment: @Valorum there is some evidence in the canon, e.g, force fields protecting against vacuum or diseases, or containing a micro-atmosphere. I suspect they work with the power of plot, though in this specific case, multiple other explanations are possible.

Comment: @PhilippFlenker - Different fields seem to have different characteristics. For example some are capable of keeping out virii and some aren't.

Comment: @PhilippFlenker two examples: TNG S2: The Child and S2 Unnatural Selection

Answer (score 2):

It's reasonable to assume forcefield tech has small vacuoles, small enough for atmospheric exchange, but not for something the size of a person to fit through. Afterall they can also talk thru the forcefield and that requires soundwaves traveling thru a fluid/atmospheric medium to transmit sound. Light can also penetrate the forcefield. 
Force fields were also capable of selective positioning, allowing the majority of it to cover 90%, while a smaller portion was deactivated to allow transport of food, drinks, and other items. So they may include small holes for ventilation.

What really brings to mind is WHY use forcefields at all, they require constant energy, they fail in case of incident or power failure. Brigs using conventional doors are safer.
In the voyager episode "Repentance" a ship attacks Voyager carrying a group of prisoners, the force fields fail permitting the prisoners to escape, while the cells are made of "Tritanium" bulk heads, strong stuff. But use forcefield doors.

As for airvents, duct work exists on ships. In the Voyager episode "Learning Curve" Tuvok and Neelix look up at the ships vent port. [image]

Comment: There's also TOS "Obsession" with an air vent apparently connected to space. Because the cloud creature gets in through it.

Comment: All the answers work. I think people can stop down voting my question now.